# Using asterisk to import all icons from material-ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

So I'm just starting to use material-ui but there're lots of imports, will there be issues in production if import everything with asterisk? Like:

```
import * as MUIcon from '@material-ui/icons';
import * as MUICore from '@material-ui/core';
```

Comment: There will be no issue. Only, your bundle size may go up at little.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it said importing full libraries (eg. `import * from '@material-ui/icons'`) could lead to slower start-up times. Therefore, I think it's better to do named imports to pull in modules that you use